# How to make a PHP function with array of arguments

Tags: php

Hi I'm new with PHP usually I work with Java, how actually the right way to write an array of many arguments/parameters in this `insertSQL` function as I have a lot SQL objects have to be inserted. Thank you

```php
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->insertSQL(
    $data[$i]->id,
    $data[$i]->location_id,
    $data[$i]->section_id,
    $data[$i]->inspection_date,
    $data[$i]->photo_entire_path,
    $data[$i]->photo_isolator_path,
    $data[$i]->pole_no,
    $data[$i]->pole_iron,
    $data[$i]->pole_iron,
    $data[$i]->pole_iron);


//Based on inserttion, create JSON response
if($res){
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]->id;
    $b["status"] = 'yes';
    array_push($a,$b);
}else{
    $b["id"] = $data[$i]->id;
    $b["status"] = 'no';
    array_push($a,$b);
}
```

Right now it looks like this

```php
$res = $db->insertSQL(
    $data[$i]->id, 
    $data[$i]->location_id, 
    $data[$i]->section_id, 
    $data[$i]->inspection_date, 
    $data[$i]->photo_entire_path, 
    $data[$i]->photo_isolator_path, 
    $data[$i]->pole_no, 
    $data[$i]->pole_iron, 
    $data[$i]->pole_concrete, 
    $data[$i]->pole_wood, 
    $data[$i]->pole_condition_broken, 
    $data[$i]->pole_condition_tilt, 
    $data[$i]->pole_condition_shift, 
    $data[$i]->cros_arm_twist, 
    $data[$i]->cross_arm_rust, 
    $data[$i]->cross_arm_tilt, 
    $data[$i]->arm_tie_repair, 
    $data[$i]->arm_tie_rust, 
    $data[$i]->arm_tie_brace, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_fulcrum_r_leak, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_fulcrum_r_broken, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_fulcrum_s_leak,
    $data[$i]->isolator_fulcrum_s_broken, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_fulcrum_t_leak, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_fulcrum_t_broken, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_pull_r_leak, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_pull_r_broken, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_pull_s_leak, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_pull_s_broken, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_pull_t_leak, 
    $data[$i]->isolator_pull_t_broken, 
    $data[$i]->arrester_r_broken, 
    $data[$i]->arrester_s_broken, 
    $data[$i]->arrester_t_broken, 
    $data[$i]->conductor_r_buyer, 
    $data[$i]->conductor_r_loose, 
    $data[$i]->conductor_s_buyer, 
    $data[$i]->conductor_s_loose,  
    $data[$i]->conductor_t_buyer, 
    $data[$i]->conductor_t_loose, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_r_35mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_r_70mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_r_150mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_s_35mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_s_70mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_s_150mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_t_35mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_t_70mm, 
    $data[$i]->connector_pg_t_150mm, 
    $data[$i]->bending_wire_r, 
    $data[$i]->bending_wire_s, 
    $data[$i]->bending_wire_t, 
    $data[$i]->ultrasonic_r, 
    $data[$i]->ultrasonic_s, 
    $data[$i]->ultrasonic_t, 
    $data[$i]->gws_exist, 
    $data[$i]->gws_not_exist, 
    $data[$i]->tree_exist, 
    $data[$i]->tree_not_exist, 
    $data[$i]->longitude, 
    $data[$i]->latitude, 
    $data[$i]->suggestion, 
    $data[$i]->descr
);
```

Comment: I do not get your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: some kind like this InsertSQL($id, array of arguments);

Comment: So is your `insertSQL` function supposed to guess which table to insert to and how to map the fields?

Comment: yes, I just want to make it just like arrays of fields, so it will looks more easy to read

Comment: You can always use [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) but without knowing why you want to do this rather than pass an array of say, named parameters, is unknown to me.

Comment: Or just pass an array in as the second argument, as in your example

Comment: What does your array look like?

Comment: Okay I'll learn about this more. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what your function should look like:

function insertSQL(Array $sqlData)
{
    Extract the values from the $sqlData variable here.
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution using `call_user_func_array`, `func_get_args`, `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions (to deal with an array of arguments):

```
...
$encoded = json_encode($data[$i]);
$fields_arr = json_decode($encoded, true); // to get an array of object properties with values.
// Also you should, probably, check the order of fields
$fields_arr['id'] = false;
$fields_arr = array_filter($fields_arr);  // for removing the 'id' field
$args = ['id' => $data[$i]->id]; // first argument
call_user_func_array(array($db, 'insetSQL'), array_merge($args, $fields_arr)); // it also may require your current Namespace in the first arg
...
// Then, the 'insetSQL' method should process the arguments in the following manner:
function insetSQL($fields = []) {
    $fields = func_get_args();
    $id = $fields[0];
    // adjusting the rest of fields ($fields[1], $fields[2] ...)
    ...

}
```

Although, I also would suggest to pass the initial object `$data[$i]` right into the `insetSQL` method as parameter and get the needed fields for sql `INSERT` statement

Comment: Thank you RomanPrekhrest, I'll have it a try, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON object as

```
$named_array = array(
            "longitude" => "12.2"
            "latitude" => "12.2"
);
$named_array = json_encode($named_array);
```

This *$named_array* can be ***array of fields***.

You can pass *$named_array* object to other function as an argument.

Then use

```
$named_array = json_decode($named_array)
echo $named_array->longitude
```

You can access any Key Value pair as $named_array->latitude